# Redirect russian URL in htaccess doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm changing my URL structure in my Wordpress website. So I'm using the .htaccess file to redirect the URLS. When I add the following code in .htaccess the url `www.mydomain.com/test/?lang=en` redirects correctly to `www.test.com`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^lang=en$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^test/$ http://www.test.com/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

My website is also in Russian.
My goal is to redirect `www.mydomain.com/шарон/?lang=RU` to `www.test.com`.

I tried to add the following code to .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^lang=RU$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD/$ /www.test.com? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

But the redirect doesn't work. I got a "can't display the page" error, I think a 404 error.

I also tried to add the Russian text into the .htaccess file. And saved the .htaccess to UTF-8 file format.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^lang=RU$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^шарон/$ /www.test.com? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Then I get the message below, my website isn't reachable anymore.

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
```

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Does anyone have an idea how to redirect my Russian urls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if URL can be specified that way when doing rewrites. Try changing it to

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^lang=RU$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^\xd1\x88\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd/$ /www.test.com? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Where

> \xd1\x88\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd

equals to

> %D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD

and therefore also to

> шарон

Hope it helps. Comment on this if you have further problems. ;)

Comment: Thank you, thank you! That's it, I only need to change the % with \x.

Sometimes it's easy if you know :).

Comment: ¿Is there any way to automatize this? I mean, this is a static example. I'd like to map ANY russian characteres {QUERY_STRING} to a server folder with the same path.